# Is the cycle space of a planar bicubic graph an algebraic variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, graph-theory

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of a planar bicubic graph on $n$ vertices, consisting of faces with $4$ and $6$ edges only. Let $X$ be a matrix of variables $x_{kl}\in \{0,1\}$.

We set up a matrix $Z(X)=X\odot A$, where $\odot$ is the [Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29).

If the $x_{kl}$ are chosen appropriately, $Z(X)$ may represent a cycle, and therefore $Z(X)$ has at least one eigenvalue of $2$.

> Does the set of solutions $\det(Z(X)-2I)=0$, that is related/corresponds to the cycle space, represent an (Reply to monstrous moonshine comments: not necessarily irreducible) [algebraic variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety)?

Comment: Do you require varieties to be irreducible?

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine no reducible ones are good enough for now...